# replace Block ROM IP in Xilinx ( Language: Verilog)

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

I am using a Block ROM IP( in Xilinx) to store values and then processing them by fetching and processing as per requirement. Now I want to use the same values through test bench so that these stored values in ROM won't show up in resource utilization. In short, I wish to give input through test bench and read values one by one just as the way I was doing by changing address and fetching pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Put the BlockRom inside translate pragmas :

```
//synthesis translate_off
    // The comments in off and on are needed.
    // Place our simulation block here (not in comments).
//synthesis translate_on
```

The code between off and on will *literally* be removed from the eyes of the synthesis (and subsequent) tools.

[UG901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2017_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) has more details.